# Prevent ipad from closing the virtual keyboard on keyboard extension

Tags: swift, ipad, keyboard, custom-keyboard

i know this is a designed part of the ipad to close the keyboard when the hardware keyboard is connected (which make sense). I understand but since ipadOS 15, the virtual keyboard will hide **everytime** a key is pressed on the hardware keyboard. This was not the case before, you could open it back and use it. We have a prediction keyboard extension which help childrens suffering dyslexia to write. I can't seem to find any documentation on this but is there a private API or something to prevent a virtual keyboard from closing inside a keyboard extension. I can see 'Grammarly' app doing it so it is possible.

So far i can detect if a hardware keyboard is connected using the GameController SDK :

```
let isKeyboardConnected = GCKeyboard.coalesced != nil
```

This is not working too inside a keyboard extension

```
public func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
     return false
}
```

I need to see my virtual keyboard at the same time as typing with the hardware keyboard in order to see the prediction view.

Thanks

Comment: Its a keyboard extension app, i need to view the virtual keyboard on every textfield. When the hardware keyboard is connected, i can show at the bottom only a view for prediction but right now, everytime i hit a key, the keyboard closes.

Comment: Have you use custom keyboard with input view?

Comment: no i have no idea can you explain?

Comment: did you get any solution ?@hugo411

Comment: not yet, the keyboard extension limitation are a pain

Comment: any idea @JayeshPatel?

Comment: hey @hugo411 did you find any solution on this issue ?

Comment: No im stuck forever

Comment: hey @hugo411 any solution ? I'm still stuck with this problem,